# Delete all records by user id laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to delete all records corresponding to user id here is my query

```
DB::table('permissions')->find($data['user_id'])->delete();
```

Answer (score 7):

if you use find method it will delete only one row,for delete all records you need to use where method like

```
DB::table('permissions')->where('user_id', $data['user_id'])->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$rows = DB::table('permissions')->find($data['user_id']);
$rows->delete();
```

Comment: Call to a member function delete() on a non-object

Comment: Try this, 

DB::table('permissions')->where('user_id', '=', $data['user_id'])->delete();

Comment: You might want to add some description to your code!

Comment: find() will return only one record whereas where() caluse condition will return all the record matching to conditions so find() will not work here.